# Prettify `-lambda`

Tags: prettify-symbols-mode

I have `("lambda" . 955)` in my `prettify-symbols-alist` for Emacs Lisp to transform `lambda` to `λ`. I would like to do something similar for `-lambda` from `dash.el`. I have tried adding `("-lambda" . (?- (Br . Bl) 955))` to my `prettify-symbols-alist` but this does not work. Curiously, it works if I make it `"-lambd"` instead, so I suspect that the previous `lambda` prettification is conflicting. How can I resolve this?

Comment: what does your code look like? This works fine for me using `(setq prettify-symbols-alist (list '("-lambda" . (?- (Br . Bl) 955)) '("lambda" . 955)))`

Comment: @JordonBiondo has a point. check your code. make sure there are no typos. i used `prettify-symbol-alist` (singular) or `prettify-symbols-mode` (instead of `-alist`) several times while typing up my answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work just fine, but you'll need to "reload" `prettify-symbols-mode` for the buffer you're working with.

For instance after starting `emacs` with `-q` and doing `M-x prettify-symbols-mode` to turn it on, in my scratch buffer I did the following:

```lisp
;; we're in lisp-interaction mode where ^J runs eval-print-last-sexp

;; starting with prettify-symbols-mode ON
;; two lambda examples, the first is prettified by default
(λ  () )
(-lambda () )

(print prettify-symobls-alist)^J


(("lambda" . 955))
(("lambda" . 955))

(push '("-lambda" . (?- (Br . Bl) 955)) prettify-symbols-alist)^J
(("-lambda" 45 (Br . Bl) 955) ("lambda" . 955))

(prettify-symbols-mode -1)^J
nil

;; the above lambdas are now not "prettified"

(prettify-symbols-mode 1)^J
t

;; now, both above lambdas are "prettified"
```

In fact, I've added that to my own `prettify-symbols-alist` in my init file, and after restarting Emacs, it's working just fine.

Comment: It works! Sorry, I had not properly sanitized my testing environment. I had some code ligatures on a hook elsewhere that for some reason were interfering (though I haven't found out why yet). This answer is great.